# Select/Back button not working on Xbox Elite Controller

Tags: input-devices, xbox-elite-controller

I'm using an [Xbox Elite Wireless Controller Series 2](https://www.xbox.com/en-GB/accessories/controllers/elite-wireless-controller-series-2) on Ubuntu, but the Select/Back button is not working.

I was first on Ubuntu 22.04 (kernel v5.19) when the issue occurred. I've since moved to Ubuntu 23.04 which comes with kernel v6.2, as this has better gamepad support, namely for paddles.

*Reference: [Linux 6.1 To Have Working Support For Xbox Elite Paddles, Expanded Controller Support](https://www.phoronix.com/news/Linux-6.1-XPad)*

Despite upgrading to Ubuntu 23.04, the Select button still didn't work across all games.

When using keyboard controls, the function the Select/Back button was mapped to worked as intended across all games.

I used [`jstest`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/lunar/joystick) to check the inputs. All button/joystick interactions show state changes except for the following:

- Select/Back (Share button, icon depicts two rectangles overlapping.)
- Home (Xbox logo in the middle of the controller.)

Specs:

- OS: Ubuntu 23.04 (kernel v6.2)
- DE: GNOME
- Connected via: Bluetooth

What I've tried:

- Using the controller on Windows. Everything works, including the Select button and paddles.
- Using the controller on another computer running Ubuntu 22.04, but the issues occur.
- Enabling Xbox and Generic controller input in Steam controller settings, but this changes nothing.

Does anyone have advice for getting the button to work, or debugging steps I could take to uncover more information?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I didn't notice this project. Installing xpadneo fixes my Home button. Also my Select button now works in `jstest` and in-game. Tested with [Terraria](https://www.terraria.org/), [Gunfire Reborn](https://gunfire.herojoys.com/en/), [Trinity Trigger](https://store.steampowered.com/app/2176930/Trinity_Trigger/), and [Spyro Reignited Trilogy](https://www.spyrothedragon.com/). If you post this as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at reviewing [the driver and support community from this GitHub project](https://github.com/atar-axis/xpadneo)? The project owner's claims, among other things, are "working Select, Start, Mode buttons."